# Github instructions on Udacity

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn android app development through Udacity, but I've come across problems with their instructions, here: 
https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853/l-1395568821/m-4419119353
Under Option 1 : Download the Github repository, I can't figure out how to do steps 2 onward. How do I navigate to a folder on a terminal? How do I clone the link into the folder? I've downloaded github already, and I'm on Windows 10. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't need Git. You can follow option 2. If you want to learn Git also, there is a udacity course.

Answer (score 0):

So you've done this

```
git clone https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2.git
```

To navigate to the project in the terminal, do this from the same terminal.

```
cd Sunshine-Version-2
```